# MVVM with Collections

Tags: c#, mvvm

If i have a model that should contain an collection e.g. book -> authors

how sould i do it

like:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

or more like:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<AuthorViewModel> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

which of this both is the more common way to do this
and how do i get the view out of the ViewModel?

Comment: Surely models manage other models in a relationship, and not other view models?

Comment: my problem is i have seen both ways and thatway i'm asking

Comment: Even though you don't want to use a framework, I would still go through the documentation or tutorials that the major frameworks come with, just so you can get your head around it.  It is a pattern, so there are differing implementations and the 'correct' one depends on who you ask.  Trying different versions can, apparently lead to that moment when you go '_Now_ I get it!'  I know i'm not there yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one is definitely wrong:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<AuthorViewModel> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

But this would be OK:

```
public class BookViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<AuthorViewModel> AuthorModels { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to M-V-VM, the lower levels shouldn't know about the higher levels.  The View knows of the ViewModel and databinds to its properties. The ViewModel knows about the model (and exposes properties relating to it), but doesn't know about the View.

Similarly, the Model doesn't know about the ViewModel.  Therefore, a `Book` has `Author`s whereas a `BookViewModel` can know about `Book`s, `Author`s and may even be able to invoke (through mediators) `AuthorViewModel`s.  But a `Book` shouldn't know about any `ViewModel` at all.

hth

Comment: so the first one is the right one and the secound one isn't programming after the the MVVM if i understood you right?  but how do i invoke in this examle?

Comment: How do you mean, invoke?  Your `BookViewModel` will have a List of Authors as one of it's properties.  The work is all done in the ViewModel

Comment: if i click on an Author in my Collection i get the NotifyPropertyChanged for him an than i do what? `AuthorViewModel AVM = new AuthorViewModel();
        AVM.add(Author);`

Comment: if the author exists, `update(Author)` would make more sense.  The AuthorVM locates the Author object and changes it, then your data service (eg repository) would do the actual database persisting bit.

Comment: ja but the `AuthorViewModel` doesnt know the selected `Author` so i have to add him first and than i can update the `Author`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if your models contain the properties that are sufficient to render the view. If you need to augment them with view specific code, and you don't want to pollute your models with these additional properties, then you would create a view model.

You could expose the model (`Book`) as a property of your view model (`BookViewModel`) if you wished, although purists would say you should create a wrapper property which delegates to the model for every model property.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'how do I get the view out of the view model', but [if you are using the MVVM design pattern then you should be using an MVVM framework](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/CommentView,guid,c61fd797-16f7-4f5f-a6fc-226f235b132a.aspx). With [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) for example, if you use view model first, then you would instantiate your view model and use Caliburn.Micro to locate the view and bind the two together.

Comment: i doesn't want to use such a framework because i want to now one my owne how to do such things

Comment: Well whatever method you are using to bind the view model to the view, you would use. For example you might have your view model as a resource in the view (this would be a view first approach). However, this is a separate question to what you have asked, which is whether to use models or view models, which as I say would depend on whether your models have enough information to render the view. You may decide that you always want to use view models, but either way your models shouldn't have references to view models, but the opposite is acceptable and required.